# Having two public IPs on one Amazon (AWS) EC2 server without using AWS VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, server, ip, vpc

I have a simple AWS EC2 server (Created before Dec 2013). I want to have two domains hosted on it, each with a different public (elastic) IP. 
How do I do that?
From what I read, the 'VPC' word keeps appearing, but I don't need any sophisticated VPC - just a simple server listening to two public IPs.

Thanks.

Comment: If you created your AWS account in the last few years you are forced to use a VPC. You really should use one anyway as it is more secure.

Comment: Please read this for multiple IP address https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/MultipleIP.html

Answer (score 3):

Have you created your account after December 4th, 2013?
If so, every EC2 instance you have is already on a VPC - the default VPC.

Each private IP can be mapped to a single public elastic IP. So what you need are more private IPs - and you can do that to either an existing instance or a new instance without touching VPC configuration!

Take a look at this [tutorial by AWS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/MultipleIP.html).

- *If you are looking to do this to an instance during setup, ctrl+f for: '**To assign a secondary private IP address when launching an instance in EC2-VPC**'*
- *If you are looking to do this to an existing instance, ctrl+f for: '**To assign a secondary private IP to an existing instance**'*

Then, on the same tutorial ctrl+f for **Associating an Elastic IP Address with the Secondary Private IP Address** to see how to add a public IP to your second private IP.

In this tutorial you will see references to **EC2-VPC** - this means EC2 instances that are on a VPC, and, as I mentioned earlier, if you created your account after December 4th, 2013, it is.

If not, you will need to take a look at how to create a simple VPC and add your instances there.

Comment: Thanks, so I guess I have to migrate my instance into a VPC, i can't accomplish that without being inside a VPC.

Comment: Make sure you're not on a default VPC first by selecting your instance on the AWS console and checking if there is a VPC ID property on the Description bar below.

If you're definitely not on a VPC, check out this AWS tutorial that might help you: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/GettingStartedGuide/getting-started-create-vpc.html

Quick tip, check out cleancloud.io to help you get better visibility and reduce your costs on AWS (full disclaimer, I'm a founder there)  :)